# Why $\frac{y}{x}$ is not in $k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

May be it is a silly question, but I do not understand why $\frac{y}{x}$ is not contained in $A = k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)$. What contradiction do I get if $\frac{y}{x}\in A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question boils down to: Are there $f,g\in k[x,y]$ such that $$xf(x,y)-y=(y^2-x^3)g(x,y)?$$
By plugging in $x=0$, this becomes $-y=y^2g(0,y)$, which is absurd.